# How to return a list or array from C block in Haskell's inline-c?

Tags: haskell, inline-c

How can I get a list or array from C block in Haskell's [inline-c](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/inline-c)? In other words, how to construct complex data in C and work with it in Haskell.
Something like this:

```
foo :: IO [Int]
foo = do
 what? <- [C.block| <what?> {
    ints = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    // ...
    return <what?>;
  } |]
  return <what?>
```

I could wrap a pointer and a size in some Haskell type, but I'd like to work with the list in Haskell, print it, encode in JSON, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a pointer to the array from your C code and use [`peekArray`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v:peekArray) to marshal it to a list.

```
import Foreign.Marshal.Array
import Language.C.Inline

foo :: Int -> IO [Int]
foo size = [exp| int* { calloc($(int size), sizeof(int)) }] >>= peekArray size
```

`peekArray` accepts a pointer argument and a number of elements to read. It iteratively increments the pointer `size` times, pulling elements off the array using the type's [`Storable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Storable.html) instance (in this case, `Int`).

It may be more efficient to [turn your array into an unboxed `Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Storable.html#v:unsafeFromForeignPtr).

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the data is copied and allocated memory can be freed?

Comment: @Igor With `peekArray`, yes. With `unsafeFromForeignPtr`, no.

Comment: @Igor PS, [Haskell bindings to `malloc` and friends already exist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v:callocArray).

Comment: Thank you Benjamin!

Comment: Ah, I'm not writing binding :) I have a C code yielding structured data. Probably with `callocArray` I should consider allocating the array in Haskell and pass it to C.

Comment: Doesn't the code above leak the allocated pointer? After the peek we need to call `free`, right?

Comment: @chi That's right. I left it out of my example to keep the code short but in the real world you would of course need to clean up after yourself